# Difference between using a for loop to run a body in a macro versus mapping `exec' over the body

Tags: hy

What's the difference between using `(map exec ~body)` versus `(for [node ~body] node)` in the following code?

```
(defmacro with-cwd [dir #* body]
          `(let [ cwd (.cwd Path) ]
               (try (.chdir os ~dir)

                    ;; Should I use this?
                    (map exec ~body)

                    ;; Or this?
                    (for [node body] node)

                    ;; UPDATE: Or this...
                    (do ~@body)

                    ;; UPDATE: Or this?
                    ~@body

                    (finally (.chdir os cwd)))))
```

Which one is safer, or are they both alright? `exec()` doesn't seem to run strings of code anymore, which I believe was changed in `Python 3`, so is it alright now? I just want to use something more concise; I'm not good at naming variables.

UPDATE: I also just realized `(do ~@body)` is also an option, which seems to be what most people do; what is the difference between that and simply doing `~@body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the difference between using `(map exec ~body)` versus `(for [node ~body] node)`

`map` collects results whereas `for` ignores them. `exec` runs a string of Python code or a Python code object, so it probably won't do anything useful with whatever the return value of `body` is.

> `exec()` doesn't seem to run strings of code anymore

[It does.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) You gotta read the documentation, my man.

> `(do ~@body)` is also an option, which seems to be what most people do; what is the difference between that and simply doing `~@body`?

In this position, nothing, because `try` already evaluates its body forms in sequence and returns the last one, just like `do`.

Comment: Huh... I tried giving `exec()` an f-string of a print function and it didn't work... Ah, well. So, I can use the other three, but in the spirit of macros, I'll use `(do ~@body) / ~@body`, whichever is appropriate for the moment. Thanks for the detailed explanation and the correction!